# Redis .GetAll() function for get a sortedset

Tags: redis

it's interesting to read the document for how to do a sortedset [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/Examples/BlogPostExample.cs#L345).

```
public void Show_a_TagCloud()
    {
        //Get strongly-typed clients
        using (var redisBlogPosts = redisClient.GetTypedClient<BlogPost>())
        {
            var newIncomingBlogPosts = redisBlogPosts.GetAll();

            foreach (var newBlogPost in newIncomingBlogPosts)
            {
                //For every tag in each new blog post, increment the number of times each Tag has occurred 
                newBlogPost.Tags.ForEach(x =>
                    redisClient.IncrementItemInSortedSet("urn:TagCloud", x, 1));
            }

            //Show top 5 most popular tags with their scores
            var tagCloud = redisClient.GetRangeWithScoresFromSortedSetDesc("urn:TagCloud", 0, 4);
            Debug.WriteLine(tagCloud.Dump());
        }
        /* Output:
        [
            [
                NoSQL,
                 4
            ],
            [
                Scalability,
                 2
            ],
            [
                JSON,
                 2
            ],
            [
                Redis,
                 1
            ],
            [
                Raven,
                 1
            ],
        ]
        */
    }
```

To do a task such as a list of popular items, looks you have to call redistypedclient.GetAll() to retrieve all records first, and then use a for loop to flag the popularity. My question is if you have a large set of data in your redis database will this operation become expensive and slow to run?